# MVC4 Elmah not logging remotely

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc, logging, elmah

I have a website which is working fine locally but not on remote server. Its a MVC4 and Elmah is configured for SQL Server.

1. I can throw a simple error and see it on elmah locally in my iis (same code).
2. Config are exactly same, SQL Server ... everything.
3. On remote server when I test the elmah with http://example.com/elmah.axd/test
   it logs the error correctly.
4. Any other error in code is not showing up on elmah.
5. I checked the Application Pool and its integrated.

I appreciate any help or idea.

Comment: Do you use both IIS and SQL Server running on the same remote server? So from ELMAH point of view, your are logging locally, right?

Comment: I use online SQL Server for both my local and remote server configuration. They have same connection string.

Comment: Can it be the same problem as described in this SO question: http://stackoverflow.com/q/6582818/1374267?

Answer (score 0):

You need to enable Elmah for remote access by adding the following configuration setting to the  section in your web.config file. The default setting for this value is false, which only allows localhost, hence why it is working on your local machine from within Visual Studio.

```
   <elmah>
      <security allowRemoteAccess="true"/>
   </elmah>
```

Make sure you HttpHandler is defined in the webServer section in your web.config file.

```
<system.webServer>
  <httpHandlers>
    <add name="elmah" verb="GET" path="elmah.axd" type=type="Elmah.ErrorLogPageFactory, Elmah"/>
  </httpHandlers>
</system.webServer>
```